# Complex table setting with m and p colums not properly aligned horizontally and vertically

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

This is a scaffold of my table which is already reduced of any dependencies.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{enumitem,longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
  \begin{longtable}{@{}P{4.3cm}@{}P{1cm}@{\hspace{3mm}}P{4.3cm}@{}P{1cm}@{}}
    \multicolumn{4}{@{}p{10.8cm}@{}}{\textbf{heading}}
    \\[2mm]
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{{texts}} 
    & 
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}m{5.3cm}@{}}{{text2a}    
        \newline  
    {text2b}} 
    \\
    text3 & RL=*  
        & 
        text4a  oder 
        \newline  
        text4b  & RL=*/*
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{text5} 
    & 
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{
      \begin{scriptsize}
        \textbf{A: }{Text6}
       \newline
        \textbf{B: }Text7
      \end{scriptsize}
    }    
    \\ 
    \hline
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I donot succeed to do two things simultaneously: Have the first and the third column aligned vertically, and have those rows with single and multiple lines aligned horizontally centered. What else do I miss?

Comment: please have alook at the answer if it suits your requirement

Comment: Why you use longtable? Is your table longer a one page?  Your MWE is difficult to understand. Can you show a picture of what look you like to have? Text in some `p{<width>}`  column you can center with `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{<width>}`.

Comment: The use of longtable is for operational purposes: In the original the are two lines with images added, and sometimes the table spreads to the next page.
My problem is not the horizontal centering but the change of p -> c when using m.

this the another line where the problem becomes apparent: Use this instead of the second multicolumn line: \multicolumn{2}{@{}m{5.3cm}@{}}{{textstexts textstexts textstexts textstexts textstexts textstexts textstexts textstexts}} it is any longer left justified but centered. 

A similar thing holds true when changing other p -> m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will present an answer that meets your requirements as I understood them: aligned columns and centered rows.
But the important thing is how I got to the answer in a very short time and very few keystrokes.

**1**  I started building the table in excel, including the TeX commands needed for  bold and scriptsize. This is not needed for the word "heading".

**2** Using the Excel2Latex add-in, I "copy and paste" the code, below
yours. See the figure. Look  the Options I chose.

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex?lang=en

I also  added the packages `multirow` and `bigstut`, both needed to run,  to
the preamble.

**3**  I then ``transplanted'' the code between `\begin{tabular}` and `\end{tabular}` obtained to your longtable environment and changed the  columns P to type C. A caption was also added for clarity.

(I forgot to also replace `{RL=*\*}` for  `{RL=*\textbackslash{}*}` in the last column.)

[image: excel2latex]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{enumitem,longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{bigstrut} % added
\usepackage{multirow} % added

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}P{4.3cm}@{}P{1cm}@{\hspace{3mm}}P{4.3cm}@{}P{1cm}@{}}
 \multicolumn{4}{@{}p{10.8cm}@{}}{\textbf{heading}}
 \\[2mm]
 \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{{texts}} 
 & 
 \multicolumn{2}{@{}m{5.3cm}@{}}{{text2a}    
     \newline  
 {text2b}} 
 \\
 text3 & RL=*  
     & 
     text4a  oder 
     \newline  
     text4b  & RL=*/*
 \\
 \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{text5} 
 & 
 \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{5.3cm}@{}}{
   \begin{scriptsize}
     \textbf{A: }{Text6}
    \newline
     \textbf{B: }Text7
   \end{scriptsize}
 }    
 \\ 
 \hline
\end{longtable}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{ Table generated by Excel2LaTeX}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{headings}} \bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}[1]{*}{texts} &       & text2a &  \bigstrut[t]\\
    &       & text2b &  \\
    \multirow{2}[0]{*}{text3} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{RL=*} & text4a oder & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{RL=*\*} \\
    &       & text4b &  \\
    \multirow{2}[1]{*}{text5} &       & {\scriptsize \textbf{A}:Text6} &  \\
    &       & {\scriptsize \textbf{B}:Text7} &  \bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%



\begin{longtable}{@{}C{4.3cm}@{}C{1cm}@{\hspace{3mm}}C{4.3cm}@{}C{1cm}@{}}  %changed P to C type
    \caption{Transplanted to longtable plus C columns}\\  % added
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{headings}} \bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}[1]{*}{texts} &       & text2a &  \bigstrut[t]\\
    &       & text2b &  \\
    \multirow{2}[0]{*}{text3} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{RL=*} & text4a oder & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{RL=*\*} \\
    &       & text4b &  \\
    \multirow{2}[1]{*}{text5} &       & {\scriptsize \textbf{A}:Text6} &  \\
    &       & {\scriptsize \textbf{B}:Text7} &  \bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The reason I explain all of this is because I worked with a lot of complicated tables, text, some equations, and mostly numbers.
Some columns are calculated from others or linked to databases. So the work is done over a long time with some other tool, other than LaTeX.
Once the table has reached maturity, has been approved by your peers and is ready for publication, LaTeX enters the scene, as the last step.
(The only exception are tables with many equations. Nothing beats LaTeX).

The rule for reproducible results is "only a single entry point for the raw data".
It doesn't make any sense to me to manually rewrite all the content into LaTeX code, a time-consuming and error-prone task.
(Especially if a reviewer later suggest changing the order of the columns or the sort order!)

When I develop a job using Excel as the main tool, I used the add-in to go to LaTeX. Other statistical packages (as "R") support other export tools to convert the data to LaTeX code. Of course, some adjustments might be needed to fit the page, orientation, etc., but the data is already there, as is most (never all) of the format.

Last but not least, I found the plugin a great teaching tool, especially with complicated formats, when I don't want to go through the many packages dedicated to tables to find a solution (or be too lazy to read the manual).
Try to do the exercise yourself with the "umbrochen" lines mentioned in the comment.

You design your table in Excel: lines, multiple columns, multiple rows, alignment, color, etc. and then paste the code generated by the plugin into a simple LateX document, with only the few packages you need to run the code, and if possible its final geometry. The response is quick, almost like a GUI, especially if you have two screens. Note that you can use your actual data, using the spreadsheet to set the number of decimal places, fonts, highlighting outliers, etc.

There is a point where you will have to do the manual adjustments that the tool does not capture, such as the absolute widths of the columns for example.
Only then do you put the result in your actual LaTeX document to see if there are no conflicts with your other packages or macros.

Since you will keep the spreadsheet as a source for the LaTeX code, any change: number of decimal places, hiding columns, reordering and updating from a database is pretty straightforward. Working with a text editor or LaTeX any of those usual tasks will be an almost impossible job with tens or hundreds of rows and data, some calculated, other linked to other sources.

Time to obtain the result for  answering the question: 15 min. Time to write this answer: 2+ hours.

Comment: Thanks Simon a lot for your time and your efforts. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @bkleine As the saying goes  ``it better to teach how to fish than ...''

Answer (score 1):

With the excellent `nicematrix` package

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}}
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}}


\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}}
\begin{NiceTabular}{P{0.2}P{0.2}@{\hspace{-1cm}}P{0.2}P{0.2}}[code-before = \rowcolor{red!30}{3}\cellcolor{blue!30}{1-1}]
    \textbf{heading}&&&\\
    \toprule[2pt]
    text1&&texta\newline textb&\\
    text2&RL=*&texta\newline textb&RL=*/*\\
    text3&&\scriptsize{\textbf{A:}{Text}\newline \textbf{B:}{Text}}&\\ 
    \bottomrule[2pt]
\end{NiceTabular}       
\end{document}
```

Comment: does nice matrix allow for multicolumns? and for lines which are "umbrochen"? The manual does not show any.

Comment: it would be better to add a sketch of your desired output  -- also if there is a shortcoming in the above answer do revert so that it can be corrected -- if the answer meets the requirement of the question -- vertical and horizontal centering of the column contents -- please accept the answer by ticking the green checkmark to the left of the answer

Comment: @bklein: `\multicolumn` can be used in the environments of `nicematrix` but the command `\Block` can also be used for mono-row blocks (be careful to use the latest version of `nicematrix`).